# Checking for updates to Windows Store apps from within the application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm trying check (programatically) for updates to Windows Store apps from within the application and notifying users about the new release.

How can i get the version of the app avalaible on Windows Store ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a documented API for querying the Windows Store to get the version of the application.

I'd suggest to achieve a similar result, place a file containing this information on a public web server and query it from your Windows application instead. Any time you push an update to the Windows Store, you'll need to update this file as well.

As Windows Store applications are by default updated automatically, this notice and check would not be necessary for some users.

Comment: It's mostly useful if you need to make sure the client is in sync with a server, in which case you can return the minimum client version directly from the server you're syncing with.